# android scrollview not working windowSoftInputMode

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-manifest, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have one activity and in this activity's windowSoftInputMode is stateAlwaysHidden

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

i created custom Xml file and in this xml i have one edittext in top position and one button in bottom position

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/u_base_min_height">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/u_base_min_height"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/transfer_headerView_height">

            <EditText

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_right">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_done"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/u_widget_height"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_blue"
            android:text="@string/u_register_next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/u_common_margin_left" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when keyboard is showing i can not show my button whitch is a bottom position,scrollview now  working.
i searched about my problem and i tryed to change windowSoftInputMode in manifest file
    `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

but i don't need this solution because my button moving keyboard up when my keyboard is showing...
how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

For that use below code

```
      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:isScrollContainer="true">
```

Comment: windowSoftInputMode ? @Rohit Heera

Comment: use  "stateHidden" only

Comment: i tyedthis solution   but my button moved up in my keyboard when it showing @Rohit Heera

Comment: then use "adjustpan" to make your button stable

Comment: can you show me  your source code? i tryed it and still not working..... @ Rohit Heera

Comment: can you show a screen shot what is actually the problem

Answer (score 0):

put your bottom button outside the scrollview. Make two separate layouts. In upper layout put your scrollview content and in lower layout put your bottom button.